# Run Cron Job On Specific Minute?

Tags: cron, cron-task

I need to run a cron job on the 3rd minute of every hour, every day.

Here's what I currently have:

```
3 * * * *
```

Is that how you correctly do it or would that run it every 3 minutes instead?

Comment: Have you read the `crontab(5)` man page (`man 5 crontab`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is correct!

If you would like to run a job every third minute you could do like this:

```
*/3 * * * *
```